# Different Styles for different Terminals

Tags: terminal, macos

I have a new M1 Mac (great machine BTW) so I need to run certain things under Rosetta. To that end, I copied Terminal.app to Rosetta Terminal.app and set that to run under Rosetta. I changed the default style for the Rosetta Terminal.app to a different color scheme so that I can easily see which is which. Worked great until I rebooted and then my regular Terminal got Rosetta style.

I'm sure they are just loading the same configs but is there a way to change that?

Thanks!

Comment: Would running just one Terminal and then use `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash` in a tab work for you as well?

Comment: No definitely not. I separated them for a reason. I don't want to get confused as to which is which.

Comment: You could easily use different background colors and/or include the architecture in the shell prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a perfect way to do this because the default color scheme (known as *Window Settings* in `Terminal`-speak) is an [application domain](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html)-level user default, which means it's set on a per-bundle-identifier basis. Since two copies of the same `Terminal` bundle share a bundle ID (`com.apple.terminal`, specifically), the last app to write to the defaults database and quit will be the one whose settings are applied upon next launch.

That being said, a decent workaround is to override the relevant keys at launch time via an argument. I can see two relevant keys when I read my defaults:

- `"Default Window Settings"`
- `"Startup Window Settings"`

Both of these keys expect a string value which matches the name of one of your predefined Window Settings names (e.g., `"Basic"`, `"Grass"`, `"Homebrew"`, etc.). So an invocation would look something like this:

```
/path/to/RosettaTerminalExecutable -"Default Window Settings" "Pro" -"Startup Window Settings" "Pro"
```

This would require you to first have `Terminal` open, so you can write an AppleScript do this for you. In fact, you can even have the script execute the system copy of `Terminal` under Rosetta using the `arch` command (as hinted by @nohillside's comment). This way you wouldn't even need to keep a separate `Rosetta Terminal.app` which saves you a tiny bit of space and also has the nice bonus of maintaining app version parity any time there's a macOS update/upgrade.

Here's an AppleScript that does this. You can change the `WindowSettings` variable to the name of your preferred color scheme for the Rosetta version and then save this script **as an application** so that you can simply double-click to run it.

```
# Change this to choose your desired color scheme
set WindowSettings to "Homebrew"

set PathToTerminalExecutable to "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal"
set Command to "arch -x86_64 " & PathToTerminalExecutable & " -\"Default Window Settings\" \"" & WindowSettings & "\" -\"Startup Window Settings\" \"" & WindowSettings & "\""

do shell script Command
```

There are two limitations of doing it this way:

1. If you've configured macOS to restore windows when an app reopens (`System Preferences -> General -> Close windows when quitting an app` is unchecked), any prior `Terminal` windows will reopen using your regular settings, not the overridden settings. This may lead to some confusion. You may want to disable this setting for `Terminal` only: `defaults write com.apple.terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false` (make sure all copies of `Terminal` are closed first)
2. If you don't have an instance of `Terminal` already running before you run the above script, macOS will treat it as if you double-clicked the `Terminal` app and you won't be able to open the non-Rosetta version by double-clicking. To work around this, you can either pre-launch your regular `Terminal` first or go with your original plan of duplicating the app and change the script to run the duplicate copy instead.